# Error handling design for a C++ API

Tags: c++, api, exception, error-handling

I am writing a C++ API on Windows with VS 2010 which exports several classes from a DLL. We are planing to support other platforms later (MacOS, Linux).

I am currently thinking how to design the error handling. I don't want to use exceptions because of the problem across DLL boundaries (at least in Windows).

I came up with the following three designs so far.

**Design 1:**

For each method the return value would indicate if the operation succeeded or failed by returning either `true/false` or `pointer/nullptr`, respectively. The client might then call `GetLastError()` to retrieve an error code (enum) which details the last failure.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectPtr;

class APIClass
{
    bool SetSomething(int i);
    bool IsSomethingSet();
    bool DoSomething();
    ObjectPtr GetSomething();

    ErrorCode GetLastError();
}
```

**Design 2:**

Each method returns a error code. [out] parameters should be passed as pointers and [in] parameters by value or by (const) reference.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectPtr;

class APIClass
{
    ErrorCode SetSomething(int i);
    ErrorCode IsSomethingSet(bool* outAsk);
    ErrorCode DoSomething();
    ErrorCode GetSomething(ObjectPtr* outObj);
}
```

**Design 3:**

Like design 1 but you can pass am optional error code as [out] parameter to each function.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectPtr;

class APIClass
{
    bool SetSomething(int i, ErrorCode* err = nullptr);
    bool IsSomethingSet(ErrorCode* err = nullptr);
    bool DoSomething(ErrorCode* err = nullptr);
    ObjectPtr GetSomething(ErrorCode* err = nullptr);
}
```

I want to keep the design simple, consistent and clean. Which design would you prefer as a client? Do you have other suggestions for a better design? Can you give some reasons why one design is better or if it's just a matter of taste?

**Note:**
There is a similar question here: [C++ API design and error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054223/c-api-design-and-error-handling). But I do not want to use the solution in the accepted answer there or use something like boost::tuple as return value.

Comment: Just a suggestion, in your second and third variants it would be better and more "C++-ish" if you use references instead of pointers for the out parameters.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, I think thats a matter of taste. The reason why I choose pointers for output parameters is because it makes it more clear in the client code that the function may change the parameter, e.g. GetSomething(obj) vs. GetSomething(&obj). Thats also the way e.g. the Qt framework handles output parameters and the author of "API Design for C++" suggests it.

Comment: If you use the same runtime in all DLLs, you can freely throw exceptions across their boundaries. If you use different runtimes, it is better to stick with C API. `std::shared_ptr` is no more safe in such an environment than exceptions.

Comment: What should be the behavior once an error has been detected? I mean, if I get an error calling `SetSomething`, a subsequent call to `SetSomething` can succeed or that instance of the API is irremediably broken?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so the no-exceptions constraint *makes* the problem... I won't question that.

Summarily, which is best depends on the specifics of your APIs: whether the values you tend to return have spare sentinel values, whether you want to force/encourage the developer to more explicitly prepare for and cope with error codes or have it more optional, implicit and/or concise.  You might also consider the practices of other libraries you're already using, especially if it's not blindingly obvious to the caller which library a given function is from.  Because there's no single best one-size-fits-all answer, this question survives in the C world after so many decades (and C++ has exceptions).

A few discussion points...

Sentinel values (as per your pointers in Design 1) work pretty well when they're anticipated by the caller (e.g. programmers tend to ask themselves "could I get a null pointer? what would it mean?"), intuitive, consistent, and preferably if they can be implicitly converter to booleans then they'd yield true on success!  That reads much better, though obviously many OS and standard C library functions return -1 for failure, as 0 is so often valid within the meaningful result set.

Another consideration you've implicitly understood: by relying on state outside the function call you introduce thread and async (signal handling) safety issues.  You can document that the developer shouldn't restrict their usage of the object from threaded/async code, or provide thread specific storage for the error codes, but it's an extra dimension of pain.  Returning or passing in ErrorCode objects avoids that problem.  Passing in ErrorCode objects becomes a constant small burden on the caller, but does encourage them to explicitly think about error handling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am thinking that solution 2 is more closely to using exceptions in the sense that if you call e.g. a query function like IsSomethingSet you can only get true or falls. In an unsupported object state the result can be meaningless, e.g. there has to be some initialization first. Whereas with this solution you can get multiple error codes like INVALID_FUNCTION_CALL.

Comment: @Hoschie0815: yes, solution 2 allows you to be very explicit, thorough and consistent, though a little more invasive and dictatorial re the style of client usage.

Answer (score 4):

I would go for approach 2, for a number of reasons.

- it's used in most cross-platform/cross-compiler C++ projects I have seen around the web (including large stuff such as Gecko/Firefox/Thunderbird);
- if you decide to offer bindings in another programming language, this design won't get too much in the way;
- clang and g++ offer an attribute `warn_unused_result` that can be pretty handy with this design to make absolutely sure that errors are not ignored.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative design I would suggest using a unified wrapper class to handle both return value and error condition in a consistent way.

With C++ usually the return value is not handled via pointer or reference arguments. If I understand you correctly, you
don't want to use exceptions for technical reasons, not because you dismiss the design of having an additional channel
for communication between caller and callee.

Using a wrapper class for return values will emulate such an additional channel, while giving you the highest level of
consistency.

(You could also add an `operator T()`, but that might be confusing in cases where you have `bool` as return value.)

```
template<typename T>
class ReturnValue
{
    public:
    ReturnValue(T&& value, bool succeeded, int error_code):
        value_{std::move(value)},
        succeeded_{succeeded},
        error_code_{error_code}
    /* Some more constructors possibly... */

    T& value() noexcept { return value_; }
    T const& value() const noexcept { return value_; }
    bool succeeded() const noexcept { return succeeded_; }
    operator bool() const noexcept { return succeeded_; }
    int error_code() const noexcept { return error_code_; }

    private:
    T value_;
    bool succeeded_=false;
    int error_code_=0;
};

template<>
class ReturnValue<void>
{
    public:
    ReturnValue(bool succeeded, int error_code):
        succeeded_{succeeded},
        error_code_{error_code}

    bool succeeded() const noexcept { return succeeded_; }
    operator bool() const noexcept { return succeeded_; }
    int error_code() const noexcept { return error_code_; }

    private:
    bool succeeded_=false;
    int error_code_=0;
};
```

Comment: Mmmh... that looks somewhat familiar. Kind of `Result<T, E>` in Rust (or its equivalents in OCaml or Haskell). @TFM, have you tried it in practice in C++? I'm curious to see if this scales up nicely in that language.

Comment: @Yoric I use exceptions, so I don't need it. But I used this concept in an RPC framework where the return value of a function executed on the server is wrapped in a message that can also contain an exception. The client receives this message and can rethrow the exception, if there is one, or otherwise just use the return value.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience several huge projects including enterprise project and internet project, which all have discussed about the question: how to use exception in C++?

When exception happens, it's good to have exception handling, for some case like invalid request or packet should not crash your whole service, and just need to catch the exception and return false. But for other cases, you'd better to directly crash the process. Handling exception is always hard, because you have to very very careful the resource clean up, and rolling the system back to correct status. And exception handling would make your code hard to maintain.

For your solutions, my preference is 2 > 1 > 3

2 is clean and simple, 1 is more like Windows API style (GetErrorCode such like that), 3 is worst that every time i have to define the ErrorCode variable first.

I prefer simple and fluent interface, so all of the 3 solutions is not fluent. http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html